# Powershell Filtering EventID with Where-Object

Tags: powershell, comparator, get-eventlog

i am trying to Filter out some EventIDs from Get-Event log like this :

```
...More code here
Get-EventLog -LogName $_ -EntryType Warning,Error | 
Where-Object {$_.EventID -ne '0|1|2|3|4|7|8|9|10|14|15|17...'}
```

However i am running into trouble with the comparator, using -ne simply does not Filter anything out, and if i use -notmatch, it returns only one result, and i have confirmed there are a lot that it's skipping. Not sure what i am missing and why it's -ne is not working at all, any help is appreciated!
Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: I guess you want to use `-in 0,1,2, ...`

Comment: Hey, that did it, thank you ! I had tried -notin before but it didn't occur to me to separate it with , and it didn't work but also did not give me an error..

Comment: Get-Eventlog is terrible slow. You might want to use Get-WinEvent for speedy results.

Here is a small example of a script I made to create an overview of users logon (Eventid 2) and logoff (Eventid 3) for the last 30 days.

Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname = "Microsoft-Windows-User Profile Service/Operational"; id = 2, 3; StartTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) }.

This should get you in the right direction

Comment: Yeah i am realizing now it's taking quite a while..But i need to filter EventIDs out and get-winevent seems to need to go into xml Properties ( like get-eventlog Replacements Strings ) to do that. I will see if i can't manage the waiting though, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Your current code:

```
$_.EventID -ne '0|1|2|3|4|7|8|9|10|14|15|17...'
```

is currently checking if the ID is literally `0|1|2|3|4|7|8|9|10|14|15|17...`.

To check if the ID is **one of the values** specified, you need to use `-in` operator, as suggested in the comments:

```
$_.EventID -in @(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

For future reference, please check [`about_Comparison_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#containment-operators) from PowerShell documentation.